# Flask only returning a single argument when parsing GET request

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create filters on our REST API using Flask, but Flask only seems to return a single argument when the same key is duplicated in the query string.

For example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return jsonify(request.args)
```

For request `<localhost>/?test=a&test=b`, the result is:

```
{
  "test": "a"
}
```

Since I want to reuse the `filter` argument to represent the AND logic for filtering, it would be convenient if Flask supported this. I realize that under the covers, Flask parses the `request.args` into a MultiDict object, which is probably why it cannot return multiple keys of the same name.

I assume I can access the raw query string somehow in Flask, but I haven't found that yet. I will update this post if I come across a solution, but if anyone else has ideas, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [rfc7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) and [The JSON Data Interchange Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf):

> An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense
> that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on
> the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not
> unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
> unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
> only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
> object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
> including duplicates.

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

So, you can't make a `json` with the duplicated keys, You can handle this with some code like below:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return jsonify(dict(request.args))
```

## result:

```
{
  "test": [
    "a", 
    "b"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `request.args.getlist('test')` to get all values for a given key.

Comment: If we send another request like  `<localhost>/?foo=a&foo=b` it didn't work

Comment: agree with @RaminNietzsche JSON spec mention :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following to get query strings

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return jsonify(request.query_string)
```